# generating output probabilities from a pmml

Tags: machine-learning, logistic-regression, pmml

I have a pmml as follows. I need to get the output probability values when predicting through a pmml reader. But this pmml only generates the value for BantStatus field.

How do i get the value for probability_1 or probability_0 from this as output?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<PMML xmlns="http://www.dmg.org/PMML-4_3" version="4.3">
    <Header>
        <Application name="JPMML-SkLearn" version="1.1.4"/>
        <Timestamp>2016-11-28T12:04:02Z</Timestamp>
    </Header>
    <DataDictionary>
        <DataField name="TitleCat" optype="continuous" dataType="double"/>
        <DataField name="RLMaxTitle" optype="continuous" dataType="double"/>
        <DataField name="Act1_rate" optype="continuous" dataType="double"/>
        <DataField name="Act2_rate" optype="continuous" dataType="double"/>
        <DataField name="Act3_rate" optype="continuous" dataType="double"/>
        <DataField name="Act4_rate" optype="continuous" dataType="double"/>
        <DataField name="Act5_rate" optype="continuous" dataType="double"/>
        <DataField name="Act6_rate" optype="continuous" dataType="double"/>
        <DataField name="AccntAct_rate" optype="continuous" dataType="double"/>
        <DataField name="sqlState" optype="continuous" dataType="double"/>
        <DataField name="BantStatus" optype="categorical" dataType="integer">
            <Value value="0"/>
            <Value value="1"/>
        </DataField>
    </DataDictionary>
    <TransformationDictionary>
        <DefineFunction name="logit" optype="continuous" dataType="double">
            <ParameterField name="value" optype="continuous" dataType="double"/>
            <Apply function="/">
                <Constant dataType="double">1</Constant>
                <Apply function="+">
                    <Constant dataType="double">1</Constant>
                    <Apply function="exp">
                        <Apply function="*">
                            <Constant dataType="double">-1</Constant>
                            <FieldRef field="value"/>
                        </Apply>
                    </Apply>
                </Apply>
            </Apply>
        </DefineFunction>
    </TransformationDictionary>
    <MiningModel functionName="classification">
        <MiningSchema>
            <MiningField name="BantStatus" usageType="target"/>
            <MiningField name="TitleCat"/>
            <MiningField name="RLMaxTitle"/>
            <MiningField name="Act1_rate"/>
            <MiningField name="Act2_rate"/>
            <MiningField name="Act3_rate"/>
            <MiningField name="Act4_rate"/>
            <MiningField name="Act5_rate"/>
            <MiningField name="Act6_rate"/>
            <MiningField name="AccntAct_rate"/>
            <MiningField name="sqlState"/>
        </MiningSchema>
        <Segmentation multipleModelMethod="modelChain">
            <Segment id="1">
                <True/>
                <RegressionModel functionName="regression">
                    <MiningSchema>
                        <MiningField name="TitleCat"/>
                        <MiningField name="RLMaxTitle"/>
                        <MiningField name="Act1_rate"/>
                        <MiningField name="Act2_rate"/>
                        <MiningField name="Act3_rate"/>
                        <MiningField name="Act4_rate"/>
                        <MiningField name="Act5_rate"/>
                        <MiningField name="Act6_rate"/>
                        <MiningField name="AccntAct_rate"/>
                        <MiningField name="sqlState"/>
                    </MiningSchema>
                    <Output>
                        <OutputField name="decisionFunction_1" optype="continuous" dataType="double" feature="predictedValue" isFinalResult="false"/>
                    </Output>
                    <RegressionTable intercept="-2.086708061828022">
                        <NumericPredictor name="TitleCat" coefficient="-0.08830152892846507"/>
                        <NumericPredictor name="RLMaxTitle" coefficient="0.1621566064638807"/>
                        <NumericPredictor name="Act1_rate" coefficient="-0.018238598197299193"/>
                        <NumericPredictor name="Act2_rate" coefficient="-0.016441453725557"/>
                        <NumericPredictor name="Act3_rate" coefficient="-0.045520608577430045"/>
                        <NumericPredictor name="Act4_rate" coefficient="0.33260315589120076"/>
                        <NumericPredictor name="Act5_rate" coefficient="-0.22925972334047728"/>
                        <NumericPredictor name="Act6_rate" coefficient="-0.03337501878673795"/>
                        <NumericPredictor name="AccntAct_rate" coefficient="0.013093373976464637"/>
                        <NumericPredictor name="sqlState" coefficient="1.0430128378571444"/>
                    </RegressionTable>
                </RegressionModel>
            </Segment>
            <Segment id="2">
                <True/>
                <RegressionModel functionName="classification" normalizationMethod="softmax">
                    <MiningSchema>
                        <MiningField name="BantStatus" usageType="target"/>
                        <MiningField name="decisionFunction_1"/>
                    </MiningSchema>
                    <Output>
                        <OutputField name="probability_0" optype="continuous" dataType="double" feature="probability" value="0"/>
                        <OutputField name="probability_1" optype="continuous" dataType="double" feature="probability" value="1"/>
                    </Output>
                    <RegressionTable intercept="0.0" targetCategory="0">
                        <NumericPredictor name="decisionFunction_1" coefficient="-1.0"/>
                    </RegressionTable>
                    <RegressionTable intercept="0.0" targetCategory="1"/>
                </RegressionModel>
            </Segment>
        </Segmentation>
    </MiningModel>
</PMML>
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? This is a perfectly valid PMML model chain - the first segment computes the value of a decision function, and the second segment converts it to probabilities.

Comment: does this pmml allow a pmml reader to read the probability values? when I predict using this pmml, all i get is just the class value, but not the probability

Comment: What "pmml reader" do you use?

Answer (score 1):

This PMML is an valid standard model chain model, the outputs of the last segment will be the final results, that mean the values of both output fields `probability_0` and `probability_1` would be produced by a compatible PMML reader. 
Takes the PyPMML as an example:

```
from pypmml import Model

model = Model.fromString('''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<PMML xmlns="http://www.dmg.org/PMML-4_3" version="4.3">
    <Header>
        <Application name="JPMML-SkLearn" version="1.1.4"/>
        <Timestamp>2016-11-28T12:04:02Z</Timestamp>
    </Header>
    <DataDictionary>
        <DataField name="TitleCat" optype="continuous" dataType="double"/>
        <DataField name="RLMaxTitle" optype="continuous" dataType="double"/>
        <DataField name="Act1_rate" optype="continuous" dataType="double"/>
        <DataField name="Act2_rate" optype="continuous" dataType="double"/>
        <DataField name="Act3_rate" optype="continuous" dataType="double"/>
        <DataField name="Act4_rate" optype="continuous" dataType="double"/>
        <DataField name="Act5_rate" optype="continuous" dataType="double"/>
        <DataField name="Act6_rate" optype="continuous" dataType="double"/>
        <DataField name="AccntAct_rate" optype="continuous" dataType="double"/>
        <DataField name="sqlState" optype="continuous" dataType="double"/>
        <DataField name="BantStatus" optype="categorical" dataType="integer">
            <Value value="0"/>
            <Value value="1"/>
        </DataField>
    </DataDictionary>
    <TransformationDictionary>
        <DefineFunction name="logit" optype="continuous" dataType="double">
            <ParameterField name="value" optype="continuous" dataType="double"/>
            <Apply function="/">
                <Constant dataType="double">1</Constant>
                <Apply function="+">
                    <Constant dataType="double">1</Constant>
                    <Apply function="exp">
                        <Apply function="*">
                            <Constant dataType="double">-1</Constant>
                            <FieldRef field="value"/>
                        </Apply>
                    </Apply>
                </Apply>
            </Apply>
        </DefineFunction>
    </TransformationDictionary>
    <MiningModel functionName="classification">
        <MiningSchema>
            <MiningField name="BantStatus" usageType="target"/>
            <MiningField name="TitleCat"/>
            <MiningField name="RLMaxTitle"/>
            <MiningField name="Act1_rate"/>
            <MiningField name="Act2_rate"/>
            <MiningField name="Act3_rate"/>
            <MiningField name="Act4_rate"/>
            <MiningField name="Act5_rate"/>
            <MiningField name="Act6_rate"/>
            <MiningField name="AccntAct_rate"/>
            <MiningField name="sqlState"/>
        </MiningSchema>
        <Segmentation multipleModelMethod="modelChain">
            <Segment id="1">
                <True/>
                <RegressionModel functionName="regression">
                    <MiningSchema>
                        <MiningField name="TitleCat"/>
                        <MiningField name="RLMaxTitle"/>
                        <MiningField name="Act1_rate"/>
                        <MiningField name="Act2_rate"/>
                        <MiningField name="Act3_rate"/>
                        <MiningField name="Act4_rate"/>
                        <MiningField name="Act5_rate"/>
                        <MiningField name="Act6_rate"/>
                        <MiningField name="AccntAct_rate"/>
                        <MiningField name="sqlState"/>
                    </MiningSchema>
                    <Output>
                        <OutputField name="decisionFunction_1" optype="continuous" dataType="double" feature="predictedValue" isFinalResult="false"/>
                    </Output>
                    <RegressionTable intercept="-2.086708061828022">
                        <NumericPredictor name="TitleCat" coefficient="-0.08830152892846507"/>
                        <NumericPredictor name="RLMaxTitle" coefficient="0.1621566064638807"/>
                        <NumericPredictor name="Act1_rate" coefficient="-0.018238598197299193"/>
                        <NumericPredictor name="Act2_rate" coefficient="-0.016441453725557"/>
                        <NumericPredictor name="Act3_rate" coefficient="-0.045520608577430045"/>
                        <NumericPredictor name="Act4_rate" coefficient="0.33260315589120076"/>
                        <NumericPredictor name="Act5_rate" coefficient="-0.22925972334047728"/>
                        <NumericPredictor name="Act6_rate" coefficient="-0.03337501878673795"/>
                        <NumericPredictor name="AccntAct_rate" coefficient="0.013093373976464637"/>
                        <NumericPredictor name="sqlState" coefficient="1.0430128378571444"/>
                    </RegressionTable>
                </RegressionModel>
            </Segment>
            <Segment id="2">
                <True/>
                <RegressionModel functionName="classification" normalizationMethod="softmax">
                    <MiningSchema>
                        <MiningField name="BantStatus" usageType="target"/>
                        <MiningField name="decisionFunction_1"/>
                    </MiningSchema>
                    <Output>
                        <OutputField name="probability_0" optype="continuous" dataType="double" feature="probability" value="0"/>
                        <OutputField name="probability_1" optype="continuous" dataType="double" feature="probability" value="1"/>
                    </Output>
                    <RegressionTable intercept="0.0" targetCategory="0">
                        <NumericPredictor name="decisionFunction_1" coefficient="-1.0"/>
                    </RegressionTable>
                    <RegressionTable intercept="0.0" targetCategory="1"/>
                </RegressionModel>
            </Segment>
        </Segmentation>
    </MiningModel>
</PMML>''')

# all input fields take 1.0 for testing only.
result = model.predict({x: 1.0 for x in model.inputNames})
```

The result is a dict with both `probability_0` and `probability_1`:

```
{'probability_0': 0.7245169429069838, 'probability_1': 0.2754830570930162}
```